# Can't reproduce "iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string", but I keep getting on server

Tags: php, apache, utf-8, iconv, php-7.4

For User Agents and Image EXIF data, my system tries to convert any UTF-8 characters, using `iconv()`.

However, sometimes I get the following error:

> PHP Warning [8]: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string

For examples like these:

```
iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU OS 10_15_5 (Ergänzendes Update) like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1.1 Mobile/14E304 Safari/605.1.15');

iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', 'Ïðîãðàììà öèôðîâîé îáðàáîòêè èçîáðàæåíèé êîìïàíèè ACD Systems');
```

And the result becomes an empty string.

However, **when I copy the above and run manually (on the same server), it works**... **I get no error**, and the characters are converted to "?".

For years that I've been trying many different things, such as different encodings, use "IGNORE" instead of "TRANSLIT", use `mb_convert_encoding`, etc...
But it's really hard to debug/fix this, if  I can't capture the real input that causes the issue, and I don't know what I can do to 'fix' this.

What can I do, so that **whatever** input is provided to `iconv()`, any non-ASCII characters will be converted to a question mark, without failing?

Comment: Do you want 1960's 7-bit ASCII, or do you want a specific 8-bit ASCII such as `ISO-8859-1`? For anyone else that is helping, try using `$s = "\u{2021}"` with `iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $s)` which for me throws. To the OP, I don't think `//TRANSLIT` guarantees `?`, just that "something similar, depending on OS" will happen. When I run my sample string through `mb_convert_encoding($s, 'ASCII')` it appears to be correct and never throws.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Illegal UTF characters can easily arise through mistakes. An example:

```
$currencies='€$';
$str = "äöü|".substr($currencies,1,1)."|def";
$ascii = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str);
//ascii = false + Notice: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string
```

It is clear for UTF-8 that mb_substr() must be used, not
substr().

With iconv, an IGNORE can be added to TRANSLIT to ignore illegal characters.

```
$ascii = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $str);
//$ascii: string(11) ""a"o"u||def"
```

Finding such illegal characters in strings is not easy. Usual debug outputs falsify these characters or ignore them.
With such problems I use this [special class](https://github.com/jspit-de/Debug) that can also reproducibly display strings with illegal UTF-8.

```
debug::writeUni($str);
//Output:\u{e4}\u{f6}\u{fc}|\x82|def
```

This output can be taken over with copy and paste.

```
$str2 = "\u{e4}\u{f6}\u{fc}|\x82|def";
var_dump($str === $str2); //bool(true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Good morning,
My problem persists because there are some characters that are not recognized by iconv. I tried several code options from various groups but what actually worked is the following:

> //Nota: Conversor de caracteres para UTF8

```
 public function ConvertToUTF8($text)
{
    $encoding = mb_detect_encoding($text.'x', mb_detect_order(), false);
    if($encoding == "UTF-8")
    {
        //Converte letra a letra
        $i    = 0;
        $conv = '';
        do 
        {
            $letra = substr($text,$i,1);
            $conv .= iconv(mb_detect_encoding($letra, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8//IGNORE", $letra);
            $i ++;
        } while ($i < strlen($text) );
        $text = $conv;
    }
    else if ($encoding == 'ISO-8859-1')
    {
        $text = mb_convert_encoding($text, 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8');
    }
    else if ($encoding == 'ASCII')
    {
        $text = mb_convert_encoding($text, "UTF-8");
    }
    $out = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($text.'x', mb_detect_order(), false), "UTF-8//TRANSLIT//IGNORE", $text);

    return $out;
}//Fim Módulo
```